# Simultaneous connections to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I'm new to snowflake and I am curious to know How many simultaneous connections can be open to snowflake through JDBC with same credentials? If there is limit to the connections with different credentials?

Comment: There used to be (in 2016) a limit on the number of connections you have have on the server side and it was just over 100. I am sure that has changed, but you could get into situations where new connections would be auto rejected by the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such limit on how many connections you can start from JDBC.
However is there any specific use case, that you need to start multiple connections?
A single connection can be used to query the DB and you can use multiple statements in the same query.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-using.html#sending-multiple-statements-handling-results

Comment: This threads talks about same situation, https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009C5Qs9SAF/how-can-i-increase-the-maximum-concurrent-requests-per-user, but this is 3 years ago and  I am not able to find current value of allowed connections